# mysql in docker container hangs

Tags: mysql, docker

Two mysql(5.6.20) instances in two docker containers (1.8.32),
master and slave build semi-synchronous replication with each other,
then users do some dml or ddl operating in master always。

after ten days or more, all the clients which connect to slave will hang

gdb -p/strace slave mysqld process hangs

pstack/perf top -p slave mysqld process show nothing

kill -9 will not kill the mysqld process

docker stop will not stop the docker container

what tools or methods can help locating the problem?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same occur today. In my case, using docker compose to bring up mysql and a range of consumers, using the current "latest" mysql image from docker hub. (5.7.16-1debian8)

I've launched a number of these, and within a week I've seen a couple of instances where mysql has well over 100 threads, all the memory on the host is consumed, and the containers are hung.  I can't stop anything, I can't even reboot.   Only a power cycle of the VM recovers.

I'll try and monitor.  I suspect it depends highly on infrastructure load (slow VM host results in slow queries backing up).  The solution is more likely to be mysql tuning and a docker bug.

Comment: thanks very much, i am trying to locate problem in docker and linux kernal

Comment: Have you had any luck?  I've had this almost completely resolved with docker-ce 18.09, but I still have instances where docker can't stop or cleanup a container once its hung.  Note that I have Ubuntu 16+ and Centos 7 docker hosts, and the issue only occurs in the Centos 7 hosts.  Ubuntu 18.04 is rock solid - this points me in the direction of a kernel bug.